# How to run the following spring example in eclipse?

Tags: spring, tomcat

How to run the following Tutorial code in eclipse?

https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

The guide talks about a built in server, but what if I want to "Run on Server" so that it uses Tomcat 7 to run? I am running Kepler SR 2 J2EE.

Comment: Create a new Tomcat instance and run it on there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The examples use STS which has a built in server.

For Eclipse, you'll want to create a Tomcat instance. Here are some simple steps to follow.

1. Right click in your servers window and select New -> Server

   [image]
2. Select Apache -> Tomcat7 -> Next

   [image]
3. Browse to your Tomcat directory and select it -> OK

   [image]
4. The next dialog you can add application. Click finish, and you should see your new Tomcat instance in the Servers window

   [image]

Comment: How do you actually run it on the Tomcat v7.0? When you right click there is no "Run on Server" option as there is no deployment descriptor (as I thought was needed for Tomcat). Is there an additional process to do that? Note that I am not using STS, but just Eclipse kepler.

Comment: As @DaveSyer notedthe example is not a web app - _"Although it is possible to package this service as a traditional WAR file for deployment to an external application server, the simpler approach demonstrated below creates a standalone application. You package everything in a single, executable JAR file, driven by a good old Java main() method."_. But a little after this, they also states _"The procedure above will create a runnable JAR. You can also opt to [build a classic WAR file instead](https://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/)."_

Comment: Also in regards to your concerns _"And because the application also depends on Spring MVC (spring-webmvc.jar), a Spring MVC DispatcherServlet is configured and registered for you — no web.xml necessary!"_

Comment: So basically, is seems like all you need to do is, instead of building the .jar in the example, you want to create a .war, as is needed to run in the web container. The project should automatically configure the tomcat server for you, as also stated in the site, and you don't need the deployment descriptor (web.xml)

Comment: There is no "Run on Server" option when right clicing on the project, maven dependencies do not show up either. Note I am using Eclipse Kepler, not STS.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a web project, so you can't "run on server". There's a main() method though so you can "run as java application".

Comment: I cant even "run as java application". I imported the project as a "Maven Project". THough I dont even see "Maven Dependencies" under "Library".